# Please,help.Could not cast value of type

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

It's tableViewController with list of locations name.
Could not cast value of type '__NSCFArray' (0x1039adae0) to 'NSString' (0x10301db00)., when i using plist

```
 import UIKit
    class LocationsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

let location = LocationsClass()
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let locationsPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Location", ofType: "plist")
    let locationsArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile:locationsPath!)!
    let stationsPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Station", ofType: "plist")
    let stationsDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: stationsPath!)!

    for locationArray in locationsArray
    {
There is a mistake in the following line
        location.name = locationArray["name"] as! String//Could not assign a value of type AnyObject?! to a value of type String 
        location.image = locationArray["image"] as! String



let stationsArray = stationsDict[location.name as String] as! NSArray
            for stationArray in stationsArray {

                let dictionaryFromArray = stationArray as! NSDictionary
                let workObject = StationsClass(nameStation:dictionaryFromArray["nameStatiom"] as! String, address: dictionaryFromArray["address"] as! String)

            location.stations.append(workObject)

        }
        }
    }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }
```

I don't know,what return

```
( 
      override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            // Return the number of rows in the section.

            return 10

        }
```

Comment: If `locationArray` is indeed an array then don't subscribe it like a dictionary... `locationArray["name"]` would work if `locationArray` was a dictionary, but it's an array. Start by refactoring your code about this part.

Comment: @EricD. There is my Location.plist http://s020.radikal.ru/i718/1510/52/6cc3f4863e80.png I don't understand what  wrong is in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `locationArray` array contains a single dictionary. This dictionary has a key "name" which contains an array of strings.

Forget your `for locationArray in locationsArray` loop and extract the first (and only) item from the array with `[0]` and cast it to a dictionary with `if let` like this:

```
if let dict = locationArray[0] as? [String:AnyObject] {

}
```

then inside you can access the value for the "name" key and cast it to an array of strings:

```
if let dict = locationArray[0] as? [String:AnyObject] {
    if let namesArray = dict["name"] as? [String] {

    }
}
```

and finally you can get your values:

```
if let dict = locationArray[0] as? [String:AnyObject] {
    if let namesArray = dict["name"] as? [String] {
        for name in namesArray {
            print(name)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you sooooooooo much, it's work,can you help me, what return  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            // Return the number of rows in the section?

Comment: You're welcome. :) Your new question is, well, a new question. You should ask it in a new post. But before that, a hint: the answer is to use the `.count` of your data source (array).

Comment: D Thank you. I did, only shows the name locationsArray[0],but does not display the other indexes(